# Is there any C scope like utility in tcl

Tags: tcl

In software development it is often very useful to be able to find the callers of a function because this is the way to understand how code works and what other parts of the program expect from a function. cscope can find the callers and callees of functions, but it is not a compiler and it does that by searching the text for keywords.

I am wondering if there is any such utility in tcl?

Answer (score 3):

Because you can do generation of code at runtime very easily in Tcl, and many APIs use callbacks, it's *rather hard* to determine statically where a command is called from. Simple searching of the code is probably the simplest way (with a recursive `grep` on Unixes, and `findstr /s` on Windows).

However, determining where a command is called from *at runtime* is much easier, as you can use an execution trace on the command of interest and introspect the call stack at that point (with `info level` and `info frame`).

```
proc foo args {bar $args $args}
proc bar args {puts ">>$args<<"}
proc caller args {
    puts "caller-call: [info level -1]"
    puts "caller-info: [info frame -1]"
}
trace add execution bar enter caller
foo [expr 1+3] [llength {s p q r}]
```

Running that interactively gives the output:

```
caller-call: foo 4 4
caller-info: type eval line 1 cmd {caller {bar {4 4} {4 4}} enter} proc ::foo level 1
>>{4 4} {4 4}<<
```

You'll get even more if you put it in a file.